# Removing rows based on the values in multiple columns in R

Tags: r, filter, subset

In my data, I need to remove the rows if the values in three columns (V1, V2, V3) are either a combination of 12 and NAs (like row 2) or all three of them equal 12 (like row 5). Please note that if all values equal NA (like row 3) it should remain in the data.

```
df <- data.frame(
  "V1" = c(NA, NA, NA, 12, 12),
  "V2" = c(55, NA, NA, 14, 12),
  "V3" = c(21, 12, NA, NA, 12),
  "V4" = c(NA, 32, NA, NA, NA),
  "V5" = c(NA, NA, 18, NA, NA)
)
     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 
1    NA 55 21 NA NA
2    NA NA 12 32 NA
3    NA NA NA NA 18
4    12 14 NA NA NA
5    12 12 12 NA NA
```

I would like the following result:

```
     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 
1    NA 55 21 NA NA
3    NA NA NA NA 18
4    12 14 NA NA NA
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set a `col` variable storing the target column names. The total number of records being `NA` or `12` should match the `length` of `col`.

```r
col <- c("V1", "V2", "V3")

df[apply(df[, col], 1, \(x) sum((is.na(x) | x == 12), na.rm = T) != length(col)), ]
```

Or

```
df[rowSums(is.na(df[, col]) | df[, col] == 12, na.rm = TRUE) < length(col), ]
```

---

**Update:** To remove rows that either include both `12` and `NA` or all of the values equal `12`, use the following code:

```
df[apply(df[, col], 1, \(x) !((sum((is.na(x) | x == 12), na.rm = T) == length(col)) & 
                               (sum(is.na(x)) >= 1 & sum(x == 12, na.rm = T) >= 1) |
                                sum(x == 12, na.rm = T) == length(col))), ]
```

#### Output

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1 NA 55 21 NA NA
3 76 NA NA NA 12
4 12 14 NA NA NA
```

Comment: Filtering with `rowSums` is more efficient than `apply(FUN = sum)`. Your first code can be adjusted as `df[rowSums(is.na(df[, col]) | df[, col] == 12, na.rm = TRUE) < length(col), ]`.

Comment: Strangely none of the codes you kindly wrote do anything on my data! @benson23

Comment: Thank you @DarrenTsai you have once again improved my code!!!

Comment: @Rara Did you test my code on the `df` you have provided?

Comment: @benson23 It is embarrassing that I mistyped the number in my real data and that is why it didn't work. Indeed your solution is the only one that does exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: The other solution offered by @Darren Tsai removes all the rows where the desired columns are all filled with NAs, in addition to removing rows including 12.

Comment: @benson23 I learned that \x equals function(x). But could you kindly explain what sum function does in this code?

Comment: @Rara The conditions inside the `sum` function would return logical output, therefore, `sum` is used to count the number of `TRUE` in the logical output.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dual condition in `filter()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(!if_all(V1:V3, ~ .x %in% c(12, NA)) | if_all(V1:V3, ~ is.na(.x)))

#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1 NA 55 21 NA NA
# 2 NA NA NA NA 18
# 3 12 14 NA NA NA
```

Comment: @Rara: Take this solution if you'd like to have a Tidyverse approach - it's equivalent to my updated code but more simple. I might rewrite as `df |> 
  filter(if_any(V1:V3, ~ !.x %in% c(12, NA)) | if_all(V1:V3, is.na))` but that's personal taste only. It helps to think about the four cases that can appear in the data: 1) all NA, 2) all 12, 3) all either 12 or NA 4) at least one value that is neither 12 nor NA.